# Php Store resized image as variable

Tags: php, image

I would like to store the output image as a variable, so I can run loops over it. I'm wondering how I can do this? I'm confused how to do this with imagejpeg? Like I want the code to finally be where I can display the image with echo $image.

```
 $imagequery = mysql_query("SELECT source FROM photos ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 16");
```

for($iii=0; $iii<16; $iii++) {

$imagetrial = mysql_result($imagequery,$iii,'source');
$imageSrc = imagecreatefromstring($imagetrial);

```
 $width = "300";

 if (is_numeric($width) && isset($imageSrc)){
 header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
 makeThumb($imageSrc, $width);
  }

function makeThumb($src,$newWidth) {

$srcImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
$width = imagesx($srcImage);
 $height = imagesy($srcImage);

 $newHeight = floor($height*($newWidth/$width));

  $newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth,$newHeight);

  imagecopyresized($newImage,$srcImage,0,0,0,0,$newWidth,$newHeight,$width,$height);

   imagejpeg($newImage);
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the function `imagecreatefromstring`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php

```
$image = imagecreatefromstring($imageSrc);

if ($image !== FALSE) {
  // the variable is now a valid image resource
}
```

As for your query, it returns multiple rows. You need to fetch the rows one by one.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT source FROM photos ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 16");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $image = imagecreatefromstring($row['source']);
    
  if ($image !== FALSE) {
    // the variable is now a valid image resource
  }
}
```

It will however be extremely resource-heavy. A better solution is to store the images on disk, and have the path to the images in the database.

Also keep in mind that the procedural mysql functions are deprecated. You should move to mysqli.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

EDIT: Your question did not specify what you wanted, **whatsoever**. This code (not tested) will draw the thumbnails size-by-side in a gallery-like fashion. There are ways to simplify it, but I've written it so it is easy to understand.

```
$num_columns = 4; // the number of thumbnails per row
$thumb_width = 400;
$thumb_height = 300;

$result = mysql_query("SELECT source FROM photos ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 16");

// the actual number of results
$num_photos = mysql_num_rows($result);
$num_rows = ceil($num_photos / $num_columns);

$gallery_width = $num_columns * $thumb_width;
$gallery_height = $num_rows * $thumb_height;

// create a large empty image that will fit all thumbnails
$gallery = imagecreatetruecolor($gallery_width, $gallery_height);

$x = 0;
$y = 0;

// fetch the images one by one
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $image = imagecreatefromstring($row['source']);
  
  // the variable is now a valid image resource
  if ($image !== FALSE) {
    // grab the size of the image
    $image_width = imagesx($image);
    $image_height = imagesy($image);
    
    // draw and resize the image to the next position in the gallery
    imagecopyresized($gallery, $image, $x, $y, 0, 0, $thumb_width, $thumb_height, $image_width, $image_height);
    
    // move the next drawing position to the right
    $x += $thumb_width;
    
    // if it has reached the far-right then move down a row and reset the x position
    if ($x >= $gallery_width) {     
        $y += $thumb_height;
        $x = 0;
    }
    
    // destroy the resource to free the memory
    imagedestroy($image);
  }
}
mysql_free_result($result);

// send the gallery image to the browser in JPEG
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($gallery);
```

EDIT: typo fixed in the code

Comment: I tried this $im = imagecreatefromstring($newImage);
echo $im; . But it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: I've updated the answer. And you can't echo the image variable, it is merely a resource. If you want to print out the image you can just echo the source directly and send the correct headers.

Comment: $Michael that still doesn't work. See my edits above. What's wrong?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish. You're running a SQL-query expecting 16 results. Why? Do you want to display one image in the browser?

Comment: I want to display 16 different images, rescaled to thumbnail size or so, side by side. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

For storing content of image into variable then you will have to save thumb image into specific path and then retrieve contents of image using **file_get_content()** function

You can save final thumb image by passing destination path as argument into **imagejpeg** function

As a solution to your problem please refer the example code snippet mentioned below

```
           $width = "300";
        $thumb_image_file=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/thumbs/abc.jpg';
        if (is_numeric($width) && isset($imageSrc)){
        header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
        makeThumb($imageSrc, $width);
        $img_content=file_get_contents($thumb_image_file);
       echo $img_content;
   }

     function makeThumb($src,$newWidth,$thumb_image_file) {


               $srcImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
             $width = imagesx($srcImage);
            $height = imagesy($srcImage);

        $newHeight = floor($height*($newWidth/$width));

        $newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth,$newHeight);

              imagecopyresized($newImage,$srcImage,0,0,0,0,$newWidth,$newHeight,$width,$height);


                 imagejpeg($newImage,$thumb_image_file);
   }
```

Comment: How would I do this in a loop? The code runs and works for 1 image, but when I wrap it in a for loop, it does not output anything. Should I store $thumb_image_file in a table and then call it? I'm worried about memory.